# How to debug 'unknown type name' when build native iOS modules for a react native project?

Tags: ios, react-native, visa

(Using ReactNative 68)

This is actually my first time creating a custom iOS native module and I've been having trouble understanding an error I'm running into. I've included a framework which I would expect to provide the interface below, but my module is seemingly not able to identify the interface type below.

I'm not really sure how to even get started debugging here. From what I can tell, this seems to be a semi frequent error when creating modules but typically has to do with circular dependencies.

Anyone have advice on what direction to go here?

```
  13 | RCTResponseSenderBlock successCallback;
  14 | RCTResponseSenderBlock errorCallback;
> 15 | VisaPushProvisioningInterface *provisioningInterface;
     | ^ unknown type name 'VisaPushProvisioningInterface'
  16 | NSString *encPayload;
  17 | }
  18 |
```